# Problem with passing variables through scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a small game where the player needs to answer questions by dragging characters to a bucket.
When spawning my characters I add an ID by passing a variable to another script. After this that variable will need to be passed to another script which checks if the ID of the character matches the ID of the question. When running the game the and moving a character to the bucket the trigger isn't triggered. Looking in the inspector shows that all ID's are 0, when they should be 0  through 9 (one per spawned character). I have attached my code below.I have tried using the return method, and am now trying to use the out parameter modifier, but i get the error:

Assets\Scripts\IDGiver.cs(11,32): error CS1001: Identifier expected

I don't understand where I am going wrong. I hope someone here can help me.
Also it is my first time asking a question here, so I hope I explained it well.

CharacterSpawner

```
foreach (var item in answerText)
{
    savedPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(9, -9), 1, Random.Range(9, -9));
    Instantiate(myPrefab, savedPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    myPrefab.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshPro>().text = answerText[answerNumber].ToString();
    answerNumber++;
    iDGiver.LetsWork(ref answerIndex);
    answerIndex++;
}
```

IDGiver

```
public class IDGiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int answerIndexNumber;
    private BucketTrigger bucketTrigger;
    public int answerIndex;
    public int newAnswerIndex;
    LetsWork(out newAnswerIndex);

    public void LetsWork(out int answerIndex)
    {
        answerIndexNumber = answerIndex;
    } 

    void Awake()
    {
        bucketTrigger = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<BucketTrigger> ();
    }
```

BucketTrigger

```
public class BucketTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    int answerIndexNumberCheck;

    public void UpdateIndexNumberCheck(int answerIndexNumber)
    {
        answerIndexNumberCheck = answerIndexNumber;
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (answerIndexNumberCheck == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: line: `LetsWork(out newAnswerIndex);` throws `Identifier expected`

Comment: Don't use `ref` and `out` keywords if you're new to programming. Stick to return values until you're more comfortable with c#.

Comment: How would you use return in here? I can't find any good reference material.

Comment: `iDGiver.answerIndexNumber = answerIndex++;`